Buen día. Vuelvo con mi pregunta a la cuál aún no tengo solución, disculpen, de verdad no sé nada de programación, estoy a penas empezando
Estoy viendo un videotutorial de Dalto, para empezar con Python. Aquí abajo dejo el enlace al video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nKPbfIU442g.
En el minuto 31, él comienza a escribir en Visual Studio Code. A él le responde la Terminal, por ejemplo, si escribe print hola mundo o si escribe 2 más 2 le sale 4.
Me dieron la siguiente respuesta que adjunto en imagen a continuación. Me dijeron que desinstalara lo que tuviera de python, en realidad no sé si hice bien esa parte, sólo eliminé archivos, si es ese el problema...alguien me podría decir como desinstalo python del todo. Luego me dijeron que debía volver a instalarlo, marcando ciertas opciones...lo hice...lo único que no me dejaba era poner un tick en la parte que decía install for all users, el resto lo hice, pero no pude solucionar. Estoy recién arrancando, hice todo lo que hizo Dalto, sólo que al llegar aquí, no puedo seguir. Pido piedad y paciencia por aquellos que saben programar...yo tengo muchas ganas, sólo que tengo este erron. Muchísimas gracias y que estén todos bien. Saludos.

En el vídeo se ve CLARAMENTE como su archivo está guardado, además él mismo indica que pulsa F5. No "escribe y le sale", está usando un comando que le guarda y ejecuta el script. Te han dicho esto varias veces ya... no sirve "escribir y ya sale", hay que ejecutarlo. Por cierto, duplicar preguntas va contra las reglas de la comunidad, edita la otra si necesitas añadir información.

Tratamos de ayudar lo más que se pueda pero ten en cuenta que la gente aquí tiene trabajos y responsabilidades reales y no están sentados esperando a ver quien necesita ayuda aquí. Decir “alguien podría decirme como hacerlo” cuando existe Google y hay miles de artículos que te pueden ayudar resulta hasta ofensivo. Si tanto quieres aprender a programar una de las principales habilidades que tienes que desarrollar es el ser autodidacta y aprender a buscar información. Si no entiendes el curso ¿por qué no buscas otro? Hay miles, tanto en YouTube como en Udemy.

Disculpen...estoy empezando y me recomendaron a Dalto, sí, puedo buscar otros. Soy nueva en la comunidad no sabía lo de duplicar preguntas. Entiendo el curso, le doy a F5 y me sale select debugger. Disculpame pero también tengo responsabilidades reales, no hubieses respondido si tienes tan poco tiempo.

Te dejé un comentario explicando lo de duplicar preguntas. Si hiciste esta, es por que ignoraste mi comentario. Y aún no nos has explicado ni siquiera si probaste con lo que te han dicho los compañeros antes. Como ayudamos a alguien que ignora la ayuda?

Para volver a instalar Python, vuelve a darle click al ejecutable que usaste para instalarlo por primera vez. Segundo, asegúrate de tener las extensiones de Python en vscode. Tercero, intenta no dar F5, sino dar click derecho en cualquier zona del código, y busca por alguna opción que diga "Ejecutar Python en la terminal". Si nada de eso te sirve, abre una terminal (en vscode, si lo deseas. Puedes buscar la opción "Terminal" en las opciones de arriba a la izquierda, o usar el atajo "Ctrl+Mayus+Ñ") y dentro de esa terminal escribe el comando:
python3 archivo.py
en vez de archivo, le pones el nombre del archivo que quieras ejecutar. Y no te olvides del .py. Hazme saber si te funcionó. ¡Sigamos aprendiendo juntos amigo!

En tu caso, para la parte de terminal, escribe:  python3 holamundo.py
